# MySQL case insensitive string matching using =

Tags: mysql, collation

I'm trying to search records using an alphanumeric "short_code" column. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE short_code = "1AV9"
```

With no collation and with column type set to varchar(), this query is case-insensitive, so it returns records with short_codes 1av9, 1Av9, etc. I don't want this.

So I tried changing the collation of the short_code column to `utf8_bin`, but now the query isn't returning anything at all. However, if I change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE short_code LIKE "1AV9%"
```

Then I get the exact row I want. Is it possible that by converting my column's collation, it somehow appended invisible chars at the end of all my shortcodes? How can I verify/fix this?

**EDIT**: It looks that by changing my column type to `binary` and trying a bunch of other stuff, it somehow padded all my short_codes with null bytes, which explains why the query wouldn't return any result. After starting over and setting the `utf8_bin` collation, everything's working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT LENGTH(short_code) FROM items WHERE short_code LIKE "1AV9%"
```

and see if you get something other than 4 as the result.

---

Edit: Hmm, your values might have trailing spaces.  Try

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE short_code = "1AV9    "
```

(that's `1AV9` plus four spaces) and see if you get any results.

Comment: Returns 8. What would that mean? From what I see there's only 4: http://samv.me/Ao4R

Comment: 4 trailing spaces didn't cut it... How can I see what those chars are?

Comment: surely it returns 8 because LENGTH returns the number of bytes. using UTF8 for that probably means 2 bytes per char, so you're getting 8. CHAR_LENGTH() should give you the 4 you're expecting.

Comment: utf8 means variable number of bytes per character, not necessarily 2.

Comment: @samvermette: I'm grasping at straws here a bit, but you could perhaps also try `"1AV9\0\0\0\0"`.

Comment: @ypercube yeh, the "probably" was the guess.

Comment: i second @IlmariKaronen, it seems the ord() suggested by ypercube shows they are null bytes.

Comment: YES! `SELECT * from items WHERE short_code = "1AV9\0\0\0\0"` returns the expected result. How do I get rid of all these null bytes? Will try @ypercube's answer about changing column type and values altogether.

Comment: @samvermette: You may also try (after backing up the table): `UPDATE items SET short_code = REPLACE(short_code, '\0', '')`

Comment: Marked this answer as the accepted one since @IlmariKaronen is the one that came up with the null bytes possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild guess. I think the table had not origiannly a collation set. Then you set the collation into `utf_bin` and that caused a confusion in the stored length of the field.

First back up your table. Then try:

```
ALTER TABLE items
  CHANGE COLUMN short_code short_code VARCHAR(48) 
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
    COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'  ;
```

Adding some characters (that are not in your data):

```
UPDATE items 
SET short_code = CONCAT('++F++F', short_code, '++F++F') ;
```

Removing them:

```
UPDATE items 
SET short_code = REPLACE(short_code, '++F++F', '') ;
```

Back to length 8:

```
ALTER TABLE items
  CHANGE COLUMN short_code short_code VARCHAR(8) ;
```

And back again to binary collation:

```
ALTER TABLE items
  CHANGE COLUMN short_code short_code VARCHAR(8) 
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
    COLLATE 'utf8_bin'  ;
```

Perhaps this will fix the incorrect length. (perhaps a shorter change - from varchar to char and back to varchar - will fix it).

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the collation then try "utf8_general_cs".

or maybe

`WHERE '1AV9' COLLATE utf8_general_cs = short_code`

Comment: `Unknown collation: 'utf8_general_cs'`

Comment: sheesh, of course, why they don't have that collation i dunno.

Comment: ok, having looked at a few other comments, what about `WHERE short_code = _utf8'1AV9'`

Comment: Still 0 results. I think there's something else going on, as you can read in the comments in my original question all my short_codes seem to have invisible chars at their end.